# Como se pasa un estate entre componentes en react?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema en react, para explicar el problema, utilizo dos paginas con sus compententes, la pagina /home y /cart, en home tengo el componete `<Home>` y en cart el componente `<Cart>`

El problema esta es que necesito que un estate que se encuentra en el componente Cart que seria precioFinal se refleje en la home, pero no se como enviarle ese estate

por que si en Cart importe Home, podria hacer asi `<Home precioFinal={precioFinal}/>` pero hacer esto me haria renderizar la home entera dentro de la pagina /cart, cosa que no quiero

Solo me interesaria pasar el state, algunos me diran de pasarlo por url pero no me serviria por que al iniciar la la home no visito a la pagina Cart, no se si se entendera mi consulta

Comment: El **state** es propio de cada componente, no puedes pasarlo, si sus datos, hacia los componentes padres o hijos por **props**. Para que lo intentas hacer suele usarse redux o algún sistema similar, que puedas tener un dato disponible entre componentes con independencia de su jerarquía o relación. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es persistir el dato el **LocalStorage**.

Comment: Podrías identificar un componente en tu aplicación que pueda ser el dueño de todo el estado [step 4](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), un componente que este por arriba de la jerarquía en tu árbol de componentes, de tal forma que puedas pasar **state as props** cuando sea requerido. Saludos

Comment: Además de Redux tienes una opción propia de React como es el uso del contexto con [useContext](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) o, el más reciente, [recoil](https://recoiljs.org/).